# Select all in a tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a `Listbox` using Tkinter and Python. I want to make a Button for `select all`, but I can't find any info regarding selecting elements using code.

```
 self.l = Listbox(self, height=12, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
 self.selectAll=Button(self, text="select all",
                      command=self.selectAllCallback())
 def selectAllCallback(self)
 # What to do here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`selection_set`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_set-method) (or `select_set`) method with `0` and `END` as arguments.

For example, try following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def select_all():
    lb.select_set(0, END)

root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
for i in range(10): lb.insert(END, i)
lb.pack()
Button(root, text='select all', command=select_all).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In the following statement, you are calling `self.selectAllCallback`, not bind it with button click. It is called before the button is generated.

```
self.selectAll=Button(self,text="select all", command=self.selectAllCallback())
                                                                            ^^
```

It should be:

```
self.selectAll=Button(self, text="select all", command=self.selectAllCallback)
```

Comment: I used it but nothing happens when i click select all, nothing is highlighted and nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks, that must have been hard to find.